# Elements of app are under the navigation android bar

Tags: android, react-native, nexus-5

**This is photo of my problem:**
[on real device - nexus5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G76zD.jpg)

When I tested my app on android nexus emulator - it was ok, but on the real android device Nexus5 I see, that elements are under the device's navigaton bar.

I tried to use this solution: [react-native-extra-dimensions-android](https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android)
 But it doesn't work - was error - I assume this is problem in library.

Also I saw this solution: [Detecting Android soft navigation keys in React Native](https://medium.com/@elliothesp/detecting-android-soft-navigation-keys-in-react-native-30163abd7113) - but I don't khow "java-code" and think that doesn't work for me.

And, in the end, I tried just to add "paddingBottom=48" style - 
It was ridiculous :)